# mysqli_fetch: returns one row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, mysqli

I am making a private message system and I'm using the `mysqli_fetch()` function in a `while` statement to return all the rows associated with the query. However, PHP only returns the last row in MYSQL.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$Connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Data");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$Val = $_POST['ID'];
$Get = 'SELECT * FROM CMessages WHERE PID="'.$Val.'"';
$Username = $_SESSION['Username'];
$Admin = $_SESSION['Admin'];

    if($Result = $Connect->query($Get))
    {
    while($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $User = $Row['Username'];
        $Msg = $Row['Msg'];
        $Date = $Row['Date'];
        $ID = $Row['ID'];

        if($User == $Username)
        {
            $MText['T'] = '<div id="Msg">' . $User . ' : ' . $Msg . ' - ' . $Date .' - <a class="TLink" href="MDelete.php?ID='.$ID.'">Delete</a></div>';
        }
        elseif(isset($Admin))
        {
            $MText['T'] = '<div id="Msg">' . $User . ' : ' . $Msg . ' - ' . $Date .' - <a class="TLink" href="MDelete.php?ID='.$ID.'">Delete</a></div>';
        }
        else
        {
            $MText['T'] = '<div id="Msg">' . $User . ' : ' . $Msg . ' - ' . $Date .'</div>';
        } 
    }
    }

   echo json_encode($MText);
   ?>
```

Comment: There are 3 rows in phpmyadmin with the same value of what my query is looking for in the $Get variable

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, which is a great thing, be certain to use [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to properly escape your data.

Comment: And what is `PID`? Give your table structure, and example data set that should be returned in your opinion. Also consider [`prepared statements`](http://www.google.com/search?q=prepared%20statements) when you're using mysqli already.

Comment: there are 2 ID fields in my table, One ID is the row ID and PID stands for Post ID which is the parent message that contains who is messaging who.

Comment: this block of php is supposed to get all the messages that belong to the parent message and display them all but it only displays the last message that was sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns all rows but , in the while loop, you are always overwriting the `$MText` variable. Therefore only the last one will be displayed with `json_encode`.

Maybe you meant to write `$MText['T'][]` instead of `$MText['T']`.